# ViewPager setCurrentItem(n, false) calls instantiateItem multiple times - Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in which each page shows loads a full screen image using UniversalImageLoader and an image URL.

I'm using viewPager.setCurrentItem(*n*, false) to open the ViewPager to any image and not always the first image.

The problem is, when I call viewPager.setCurrentItem(*n*, false), it calls instantiateItem *(n+1)* times and the universal image loader loads all those *(n+1)* images which is inefficient for me.

I want my ViewPager to set the current item to *(n)* and only instantiate the preceding and following pages. Is it possible?

Comment: View pager contains fragments or Views ?

Comment: Views with a PagerAdapter

Comment: its default behaviour. Try to have number 'n' global and with position you can achieve task.. but scrolling again has to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

and then your view pager just loads (n-1) , (n) and (n+1) pages.\
also if you use fragments in your view pager you can force it to load fragment #n by something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //Load your image
      }
        else {  }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), the use of `setCurrentItem(int position, boolean smoothScroll)` and `setCurrentItem(int position)` will scroll the `ViewPager` to the given position. Therefore all the views that will be scrolled through will be loaded. So you shouldnt call that method if you dont want to load all those views.

Instead you could try to adjust the positions of the items in your `List` you use for your `PagerAdapter`. So instead of scrolling the `ViewPager` to position 5, you could try to move the item at position 5 in your `List` to position 0 and then update the `PagerAdapter`. You could for example remove the first 4 items and place them at the end, this will reduce the amount of views that have to be loaded. But I dont know if that meets your requirements.